# Alternatives to file polling?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, terminal

In the following code, I have to poll `$tmp_input` to continue executing the code because `wezterm cli send-text` is asynchronous. This makes sure that `$tmp_input` is ready.

```
tmp_input=$(mktemp ./tmp_input.XXXXXX)

echo "read input; echo \$input > $tmp_input" | wezterm cli send-text --pane-id $bottom_pane_id --no-paste

while [ ! -s "$tmp_input" ]; do
    sleep 1
done

input_value=$(cat "$tmp_input")
rm "$tmp_input"

echo "Input was: $input_value" | wezterm cli send-text --pane-id $bottom_pane_id --no-paste
```

The code works, but I was wondering if there is another way of accomplishing the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a named pipe with `mkfifo` instead, and read that. Reads will block until something has written to the pipe, no manual polling required. Something like:

```
tmp_input=$(mktemp -d ./tmp_input.XXXXXX)
mkfifo "$tmp_input/fifo"

echo "read input; echo \$input > $tmp_input/fifo" | wezterm cli send-text --pane-id $bottom_pane_id --no-paste

input_value=$(cat "$tmp_input/fifo")
rm "$tmp_input/fifo"
rmdir "$tmp_input"

echo "Input was: $input_value" | wezterm cli send-text --pane-id $bottom_pane_id --no-paste
```

I switched to `mktemp -d` as a hopefully safer alternative to getting a name from `mktemp` and then using that name with `mkfifo`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you heard of [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)?
It sounds like what you want.

(I often use [entr](https://eradman.com/entrproject/) to execute on file changes - but I think you can achieve your goal with inotifywait.)

Comment: I was going to suggest [`inotify`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), but this works better for a bash script

Comment: As a quick note, this approach is Linux-specific (there are equivalent interfaces on pretty much all other modern platforms, but they do not always have shell commands for interacting with them, and when they do it’s a different shell command).

Answer (score 4):

`tail` command has a `-f`/`--follow` flag which tells it to *"output appended data as the file grows"*. Then you can use the `head` command to wait until the first line is written to the file.

```
input_value=$(tail -f "$tmp_input" | head -1)
```

Note it will only work if there's a new line at the end of the first line (which is true in your case, since `echo` adds a new line to the end of the string by default).

Comment: Very clever!...

Comment: Note that this may still be polling the file internally, though it will often be doing so in a way that is more efficient than a simple while loop in a shell script.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I don't understand the comment. Of course it's "polling". The question was literally about file polling. And anyway, FWIW, at least in my `tail` implementation, it's still using the `inotify` mechanism for polling, it doesn't loop with sleep, if that's what you were trying to hint. But even if some implementations of `tail` do that, I don't see what's wrong with that.

Comment: @aviro The question was asking about _alternatives_ to polling the file for changes. `tail -f` is definitely cleaner than doing it manually, so I would still consider this a good answer, but if someone is very specifically looking to not poll at all, it’s important to know that some implementations do in fact poll the file for changes. And, for the record, `inotify` isn’t polling, it’s event triggered even down at the lowest level in the kernel, just like essentially all other kernel-level APIs for this.